# Detect and convert Simple Products to Bundle if equivalent (CE 1.7.0.2)

Tags: cart, bundle

Does anyone know if it's possible to have Magento detect if the simple items in a cart are equivalent to a bundle, and if so convert it to the bundle product in the cart.

i.e. Product A is £100. Product B is £200. Both are available individually. Bundle X consists of product A and product B for a fixed price of £250. If someone adds Product A, then later Product B, I want Magento to detect that this is equivalent to Bundle X and so show Bundle X in the cart instead.

Thanks

Neil

Comment: Did you manage to resolve your issue?

Comment: I ended up using Shopping Cart Price Rules. However, http://amasty.com/special-promotions-pro.html claims to do a similar thing, where two products existing in the cart cause a discount to be applied.

Comment: I've used that extension a few times and it works pretty well. Can you add your solution as accepted answer to close the question?

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible out of the box but you can probably do something like this from an observer hooking the `checkout_cart_product_add_after` event.

So after a product is add to cart get all the cart items check the product ID's against the bundled product link table in the database. This will determine if there is a bundled product you can use. Next step would be to remove the simple products from the cart adding a bundled product one.

This is however a pretty tricky undertaking.

- How to handle cart merges and items from wishlists
- The load of iterating all combinations of products in the cart vs the existing bundled products would be quite high
- Any other freaky fringe issues I can't think off right now.

Personally I think you're better off adding the bundled product as a cross- or upsell product to the simple product letting people now you can purchase this item in a bundle.

Comment: That was nice and clear. Thanks for this greate answer. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using Shopping Cart Price Rules. However, amasty.com/special-promotions-pro.html claims to do a similar thing, where two products existing in the cart cause a discount to be applied.